# datepicker doesnt work as php include

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, datepicker

I have a reservations booking bar that uses jquery datepicker from a small calendar button. When I go to the direct url of the php page, everything works fine. When I place the reservations booking bar as a php include on my wordpress theme's header.php file, the calendar button function doesn't work.

```
Main Site
http://192.185.167.175/~laurente/belle/

Reservations bar page
http://192.185.167.175/~laurente/belle/rez/phpinclude.php
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 path errors on you site

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://192.185.167.175/~laurente/belle/rez/js/jquery-1.10.2.custom.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://192.185.167.175/~laurente/belle/js/jquery-1.10.2.js
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

its seems as though the paths to the JS files are not correct namely these two

```
http://192.185.167.175/~laurente/belle/rez/js/jquery-1.10.2.custom.js
http://192.185.167.175/~laurente/belle/js/jquery-1.10.2.js
```

Comment: .custom.js should be a cut-down version of the .js, so having both is redundant.

Comment: If I put the `code`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.185.167.175/~laurente/belle/rez/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`code` on the include page, the slider on my homepage breaks. If I leave it off completely, the calendar doesn't work on either.

Comment: also, if i don't hardcode the js link to the include file, i get it to work on the local file, but it gets stripped on the main page of the site. is it a wordpress conflict?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't just include a PHP file into a WordPress page. You should ideally split up the stuff that should go into the header and the stuff that should go into the body.

That said, I think your main problem is loading jQuery twice (once in WordPress header, once in your PHP include). So if you cut out the line `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` from your PHP file and one of the jQuery UI includes, you may find it works.

For rapid testing purposes, you may find it useful to create another PHP file that has the JS links and includes the phpinclude.php - that way you have a common phpinclude.php that can be accessed in and out of WordPress.

Comment: i need to put the include on the header.php because the booking bar needs to be in a location that resides in the header area. I tried it as an iframe, but the dropdown boxes get stuck within the frame and it messes up the functionality of the dropdown menu. I removed the isntances of the 1.10.2.js but i still can't get it to work

Comment: I meant the HTML header and body. There are official ways to inject things into the right places in WordPress so that things fire in the right place. Currently your jQuery-dependent code is firing *before* jQuery is loaded.